# How can I consolidate these specific columns in a single row once it meets the condition below in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I do have a user that has multiple transaction in a day and I only need to display a specific user and it's equivalent status in a single row that meets the condition below :

STATUS CONDITION:
(per user, per day, per transaction)

• Completed - if there is at least 1 completed transaction

• In Progress - if there is no any completed but at least 1 in progress

• Hold - if all transaction is in hold

Sample Table
MyTable

| User | Status |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | Completed |
| A1 | In Progress |

So the expected Result should be :

| User | Status |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | Completed |

I tried this query for getting the status  but it only returns duplicate user and status of each transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the specific user and equivalent status; the following query shall word for you.

```
SELECT 
  User, 
  IF(COUNTIF(vwAHDR.ActivityStatus = 'Completed') > 0, 'Completed', IF(COUNTIF(vwAHDR.ActivityStatus = 'Pended') > 0, 'Pended', 'Held')) AS TaskStatus
FROM 
  your_table vwAHDR
GROUP BY 
  User;
```

Input table :

| User | Status |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | Completed |
| A1 | In Progress |

Output :

| User | Status |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | Completed |

If you are calculating STATUS CONDITION per day;

You have to change the group by to :

`GROUP BY User, DATE_TRUNC('DAY', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());`

In the place of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`; you can pass any date or `date_column`

Comment: Hi , @ Tushar for the current_timestamp I tried this '2022-09-23 11:00:00 UTC' but im getting an error a valid date part name is required can you give me a sample format ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi im still facing the same issue in TIMESTAMP a valid date part name is required?

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately i'm still getting the same error .Thanks.

Comment: Can you change it to `DATE_TRUNC('DAY', TIMESTAMP '2022-09-23 11:00:00', 'UTC');`

Comment: I have tried this instead DATE_TRUNC(CAST('2021-01-01 02:44:00' AS DATETIME),DAY).

Comment: Did `DATE_TRUNC(CAST('2021-01-01 02:44:00' AS DATETIME),DAY)` work ?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work same error.

Comment: Well, I may have to workaround it.
Does the answer solve your original problem ?